# How do I use DrawImage

Tags: java

Ok Im really new to java, and I cant seem to get drawImage() to work, Plz help Here is my code:

```
package Main;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MainMethod extends JFrame{
    public MainMethod(){
        setTitle("Game");
        setContentPane(new GamePanel());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        MainMethod MM = new MainMethod();
    }
}
```

My my class with the Drawimage

```
package Main;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements Runnable{

//Variables
private static final int Height = 500;
private static final int Width = 500;
private static final int x = 225;
private static final int y = 225;

private boolean running = false;
private BufferedImage image;
private Graphics2D g2;
public Thread thread;

//constructor
public GamePanel(){
    super();
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
    setFocusable(true);
    requestFocus();
}

//addNotfity
public void addNotify(){
    if(thread == null){
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }
}
//init
public void init(){
    running = true;
    image = new BufferedImage(Height, Width,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    g2 = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
}
//run
public void run() {
    init();

    while(running){
        drawChar(g2);
        try{
            Thread.currentThread();
            Thread.sleep(50);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

Image Rect = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\eduar_000\\Desktop\\Rect.png").getImage();

public void drawChar(Graphics2D g){
    g.drawImage(Rect, 225,225,null);
}

}
```

Please Help me I have no Idea what I'm doing wrong! Java is really confusing for me!

Comment: "_I cant seem to get drawImage() to work_" It would help if you explained what was happening vs. what you expected to happen.

Comment: ok I just saw a blank screen pop up and i expected to see a square in the middle

Comment: Where did you obtain this code? It doesn't look anything like code you'd use to draw a square, so looks like you're borrowing the wrong code.

Comment: @Takendarkk: he/she has the JFrame displaying code at the top.

Comment: I wrote it, I learned java in videos so i used what i learned and tryed to make something

Comment: Why are you trying to use threading? What is the purpose of that? Again, please explain what you're trying to do ***in detail***.

Comment: Your JPanel doesn't seem to be calling any of the methods that it defines such as `run()` or `init()`.

Comment: Start here: [Painting with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html).

Comment: @Takendarkk: yes it is

Comment: @user3656530 Where exactly do those methods get called from? I for sure could be missing it. The only methods I see being called in your JPanel class are `super();` `setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));` `setFocusable(true);` and `requestFocus();`

Comment: @boolean Whether this post deserves an upvote or not is up for debate, but your reasoning is horrible.

Comment: @user3656530 where are you calling the addNotify() method?

Comment: Java is one of the easiest languages to learn. You shouldn't give up so easily. If it's any consolation, your code is very over complicated. If you started with more basic code you would learn more easily.

Comment: No you shouldn't, but you will want to start to learn to walk before trying to run. Get a beginning Java book and go through it. It's how many of us, myself included learned.

Comment: Hell, I've been messing with Java for almost 3 years now and I still learn new things everyday just browsing around this site.

Comment: The addNotify Method was being called I checked, but it doesnt matter now

Answer (score 0):

You never called addNotify() to run the thread in the GamePanel class.

After setVisible(true) in your MainMethod class constructor, add the call for your addNotify() method.

I fixed it here for you:

```
package Main;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MainMethod extends JFrame {

    public MainMethod() {
        setTitle("Game");
        GamePanel myPanel = new GamePanel();
        setContentPane(myPanel);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
        myPanel.addNotify();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        MainMethod MM = new MainMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: The addNotify Method was being called I checked

Comment: Where was it being called?

Comment: its runs automatically

Comment: It wouldn't run unless you edited your code to mine above. No where on the code you provided in your original post could possibly result in addNotify() to be called.

Comment: Did you read the part of the accepted answer that says, "if you override it, you'll probably break it"?

Comment: it doesnt matter i dont care about java anymore im going back to webdesign

Comment: I don't understand why you are giving up on a language. I highly doubt you were more than novice at web design from that attitude.